# Android - How to Share image using URI?

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

I have image uri & I am trying to share it using below code, but it's not working.

Share intent is opened but no image is present there. Please help me with this

```
private fun ivShareClickListener(position: Int) {
        var file = File(dataList[position].uri.path)
        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        //sharingIntent.type = "*/*"
        val apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context, context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", file
        )
        sharingIntent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "*/*")
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(context, Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"), null)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void shareImage() {
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myImage.png";
File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));

}
```

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory` is deprecated in SDK 29. Avoid using this

Comment: But what is worse is that no FileProvider is used.